# Devise Users customization causes MissingTemplate on Users, index action in root_path on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise, missing-template

(Rails 3.1, Heroku cedar, ruby 1.9.3, macosx, eclipse, git)

My application is deployed on heroku cedar, and the devise sign-in layer worked fine in the last version but the users-path now throws a missing template error.  It works fine on my development machine.

The two big changes I made to the latest is - 
1) generating the Users model/view/controller from Devise so I could customize.
2) Added a path prefix to the devise user paths (i.e. registration)

As a test on Heroku, change root_path to a different controller/index (i.e. messages_path), which allowed access to the application.  Everything worked, except a click to the home link, which tries again to go to the users_path (same missing template error):

```
<%= link_to image_tag("homeIcon.png"), users_path, :method =>"GET", :id =>"menulink", :title => "Go Home." %>
```

I am desperate for any insight into this issue because I can't figure out what to do except not use Devise and Users this way on Heroku.
Any and all ideas are greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Anne

(Note on research: Searched on the error message; similar issues, but nothing about failing to go to root_path of users#index, nothing related to Devise and Users customization causing error message; reviewed questions list proposed by stackoverflow engin)

Login output local development in eclipe:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 
(0.2ms)  SHOW search_path
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
Redirected to [local-machine]/myprefix/users/sign_in
...
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 08:31:13 -0400
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
```

Login output on Heroku.
Users sign-in, but users/index.html page causes “Sorry, but something went wrong” page.

```
Started GET "/myprefix/users/sign_in" for ...
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application...dyno=web.1
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (53.2ms)
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
cache: [GET /myprefix/users/sign_in] miss
…
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/myprefix/users/sign_in
host=myapp.herokuapp.com                            
…
Started POST "/myprefix/users/sign_in" 
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓"... 
Redirected to http://myapp.herokuapp.com/
cache: [POST /myprefix/users/sign_in] invalidate, pass
method=GET path=/ host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=f...
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 49ms
Started GET "/" for ...
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/index, application/index 
with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}.
Searched in:
 ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/index, application/index with 
 {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}.
Searched in:
* "/app/app/views"
* "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.8/app/views"
):
cache: [GET /] miss
(no other output)

File.properties shows location (i.e. eclipse ide)
[path-to-my-rail-app]/app/views/users/index.html.erb
[path-to-my-rail-app]/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

routes.rb
MyApp::Application.routes.do
devise_for :views
devise_for :admins
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'myprefix'
resources :users do
    resources :x, only: [:new, :create, :index, :edit,:destroy]
    resources :y, only: [:new, :create, :index, :update, :destroy]
    resources :z, only: [:new, :create, :index, :edit,:destroy,:update] do
       get :q, :on => :member
    end
end
```

`rake routes output:`

```
new_user_session GET    
       /myprefix/users/sign_in(.:format) 
       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
user_session POST   
       /myprefix/users/sign_in(.:format)   
       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
destroy_user_session DELETE 
       /myprefix/users/sign_out(.:format) 
       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
user_password POST   
       /myprefix/users/password(.:format) 
       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
new_user_password GET    
       /myprefix/users/password/new(.:format)    
       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
edit_user_password 
   GET    
      /myprefix/users/password/edit(.:format)  
       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   PUT    /myprefix/users/password(.:format)                 
       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration 
   GET    /myprefix/users/cancel(.:format)
       {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
user_registration POST   /myprefix/users(.:format)  
        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
new_user_registration GET    
       /myprefix/users/sign_up(.:format) 
        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
edit_user_registration GET
      /myprefix/users/edit(.:format)
        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
     PUT    /myprefix/users(.:format)
        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
     DELETE /myprefix/users(.:format)
        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}

users GET    /users(.:format) {:action=>"index",    :controller=>"users"}
      POST   /users(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                           
         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                      
         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                           
         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                           
         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
    DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                           
         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
root        /                                              
         {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
```

gemfile:
    source 'http://rubygems.org'
    gem 'bundler'
    ruby "1.9.2"
    gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
    gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'devise'

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.active_users   
  end
end
```

appliction.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'devise'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's fixed, but in the weirdest way.  Thanks to all the stackexchange posts that gave me the incremental insights, and to Raul who pushed the verification idea.

Here's the gist of it for anyone else stuck in cloud-hell.

1 - views/Users needed to be views/users.  somehow my local environment create *U*sers.
The entire /user location seemed to be pushed to heroku, but apparently not.

2 - (after Raul's question, and an hour trying to find the heroku directory structure) 
Made a simple typo change to /users/index.html, to see if there was an error when I tried to commit it.
During the commit (eclipse git window), I noticed the filename in the project explorer flicking between 'Users/' and 'users, the entire time.

Once the git commit completed and I did yet another heroku push master, the problem was solved.  I now land on /users/index.html

Thanks to everyone for the save, I love this site.

Anne

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your application can't find the `users/index.html.erb` file.

Can you confirm that the file exists, and that it has been pushed to production too?

Comment: I'm fairly new to heroku and can't find out how to verify files on the server.  All I have to go on is the git repository.  Heroku is saying "everything is up-to-date".

I'm looking the heroku CLI, but can't find anything.